# how to cancel interactively task in dolphindb

Tags: dolphindb

When running interactive tasks with GUI in dolphindb, is there any way to cancel the interactive tasks? After running a long-term task, I found that I still need to modify the script to run again. At this time, the running button is no longer available. Is there any other way besides closing and restarting the data nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Use function `getConsoleJobs` to get a list of interactive jobs. Find out the rootJobId of the job you would like to cancel. Then call function `cancelConsoleJob` to cancel the desired job.